# Combination of counter and user input using Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller

I am a student and am studying threads recently. What I am trying to do is to implement MVC pattern that manages functionalities such as start counting, stop counting, reverse counting and etc...

My final goal is that, I need to get an user input whilst the counter is counting from 1, and if I input 2 (assuming that option 2 is stopping the counter), the counter should stops counting.

For example:

```
Counting...
1
2
3
(If I press 2 here)
Counter stopped running!
```

Because this is the homework from my college, I cannot upload here the code I implemented.

What I did was,

MVC pattern:

Controller class= gets model and view with Controller constructor. This class also provides service() method that uses switch case to make user to input to select the options to run the functionality for counting (eg) case1: startCounting() case2: stopCounting(), and etc...)

View class = provides options using System.out.println and displayMenu() function.

Model class = implements the functionalities such as startCounting(), stopCounting and etc...

I now need to add threads for this implementation in order to interact the user input with this counting process.

Can I please get any hints? For example, which class should I extend the Thread and in what way should I implement run() menthod?

Skeleton code:

**CountController class**

```
public class CounterController {
    private Counter model;
    private CounterView view;

    public CounterController(Counter model, CounterView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Counter {
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean counting = false;
    private Integer ceiling = null;
    private Integer floor = null;
    private boolean reverse = false;

    public void startCounting() {
        counting = true;
        while (counting && checkLimits()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                count = reverse ? count - 1 : count + 1;

                // You should replace this print with something observable so the View can handle it
                System.err.println(count);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        }
    }

    public void stopCounting() {
        counting = false;
    }

    public void setReverse(boolean reverse) {
        this.reverse = reverse;
    }

    public void setCeiling(Integer ceiling) {
        this.ceiling = ceiling;
    }

    public void setFloor(Integer floor) {
        this.floor = floor;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void resetCount() {
        count = 0;
    }

    private boolean checkLimits() {
        if (null != ceiling && count >= ceiling) {
            return false;
        }
        if (null != floor && count <= floor) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**View Class**

```
public class CounterView {
    private Counter model;

    public CounterView(Counter model) {

        this.model = model;
    }

    public void launch() {

    }
}
```

**ViewUntil Class**

```
    class ViewUtils {
    static int displayMenu(String header, String[] options, String prompt) {
        System.out.println("\n" + header);

        for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + options[i]);
        }

        while (true) {
            Integer response = getInt(prompt, true);

            int selection = response != null ? response : -1;

            if (selection > 0 && selection <= options.length) {
                return selection;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid menu selection");
            }
        }
    }

    static String getString(String prompt, boolean allowBlank) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String response;
        do {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            response = s.nextLine();

            if (!allowBlank && "".equals(response)) {
                response = null;
                System.out.println("Blank entry is not allowed here.");
            }
        } while (null == response);

        return response;
    }

    static Integer getInt(String prompt, boolean allowBlank) {

        int response;
        do {
            String str = getString(prompt, allowBlank);
            if ("".equals(str)) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                response = Integer.parseInt(str);
                return response;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input - number required");
            }

        } while (true);
    }

    static Boolean getBoolean(String prompt, boolean allowBlank) {
        prompt = prompt + "(y/n) ";
        Boolean response;
        do {
            String str = getString(prompt, allowBlank);
            if ("".equals(str)) {
                return null;
            }

            if ("y".equals(str.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }

            if ("n".equals((str.toLowerCase()))) {
                return false;
            }

            System.out.println("Invalid input - must be y or n");

        } while (true);
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter model  = new Counter();
        CounterView view = new CounterView(model);
        CounterController controller = new CounterController(model, view);

        controller.service();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! You need to post the code. Otherwise the question will get closed.

Comment: can I just upload the skeleton code? this is not a version that is fully implemented

Comment: Yes, of course, but the readers will decide if it's enough details to answer.

Comment: I uploaded the skeleton code!

Answer (score 0):

Using "volatile" to coerce the thread Counter to check for the newest setting values in memory and not in its "cache".

```
public class Counter {
    private int count = 0;
    private volatile boolean counting = false;
    private volatile Integer ceiling = null;
    private volatile Integer floor = null;
    private boolean reverse = false; 
    ...
}
```